# Android Studio Watches are not persistent

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, watch

Intellij IDEA documentation states the the Watches panel in Debug console should be persistent.  However, I must constantly re-define the variables I would like to watch in the panel. Is there a setting that I am missing? I am new to Android Studio and Intellij.

Comment: What do you mean by "constantly"? When do the watches you've entered disappear?